# onInit function of PaypalButtons component is never called

Tags: reactjs, paypal, react-props

Without any changes to our codebase concerning Paypal functionality, the following errors started popping up whenever we attempted to load the `PaypalButtons` component from `react-paypal-js`.

With a cleared cache:
[An undefined Paypal SDK version seems to get loaded when we have a clear cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlyjW.png)

After a short while of waiting for the button to become clickable:
[It seems to me that the problem signalled here has something to do with the fact that those functions do not exist on whatever SDK version gets loaded (which is probably none as it is undefined)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7sqp.png)

I simply tried to make a dummy payment, but the button never became clickable. In our implementation, it becomes clickable as soon as the `onInit` function from the `PaypalButtons` component runs.

How we call the `PaypalButtons` component:

```
const PaypalButton = ({ documentId, history, getPaymentForInvoice }: PaypalButtonProps) => {
   const [ isInitialized, setIsInitialized ] = useState(false)
   const [{ options, isPending, isResolved, ...rest }] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

   useEffect(() => {
      setIsInitialized(false);
   }, [documentId])

   const onCreateOrderHandler = async (data: any, actions: any): Promise<string> => {
      console.log('Creating payment');

      const paymentId = await getPaymentForInvoice(documentId);

      if (paymentId) {
         return Promise.resolve(paymentId)
      }

      return Promise.reject()
   }

   const onApproveHandler = async () => {
      console.log('Payment approved');

      onRedirectToLoadingUrl();
   }

   const onErrorHandler = async () => {
      console.log('Received error during payment');

      onRedirectToFailureUrl();
   };

   const onCancelHandler = async () => {
      console.log('Payment cancelled');
   };

   const onInitHandler = (data: any) => {
      console.log('Paypal buttons are initialized');
      setIsInitialized(true);
   };

   const onRedirectToLoadingUrl = () => {
      history.push(`${RestURLConstants.baseAppPaths.paymentLoadingPath}-${documentId}`)
   }

   const onRedirectToFailureUrl = () => {
      history.push(`${RestURLConstants.baseAppPaths.paymentFailurePath}-${documentId}`)
   }

   return isResolved ? (
      <PayPalButtons
         disabled={!isInitialized}
         forceReRender={[documentId]}
         createOrder={onCreateOrderHandler}
         onApprove={onApproveHandler}
         onInit={onInitHandler}
         onCancel={onCancelHandler}
         onError={onErrorHandler}
      />
   ) : null;

}
```

How our `PaypalScriptProvider` is set up:

```
import { PayPalScriptProvider } from '@paypal/react-paypal-js';

<PayPalScriptProvider
    options={{
        'client-id': PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
        components: `buttons`,
        currency: `EUR`,
        commit: true,
        'data-usercentrics': `PayPal`,
        'data-namespace': `paypal_sdk`,
        'disable-funding': `credit,card,bancontact,blik,eps,giropay,ideal,mybank,p24,sepa,sofort,venmo`
    }}
>
    <Authenticate />
    <RegisterSharedEvents />
    <PagesMainRouting />
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

As I mentioned, no recent codebase change has been made in these components, we simply woke up to this happening. I expected the `onInit()` function to be called, however it never does, with the errors described above being present. `isResolved` from the `usePayPalScriptReducer` is set to true, which does indeed point that some PayPal SDK instance is present, but with an undefined version.
Note: The `PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID` const is stored in a config file and taken from our env.

Comment: Don't attempt to load the SDK multiple times on page load and don't set data-namespace unless it's necessary, which it should not be from what you've explained of your use case

Comment: Fair, thank you for the suggestions, I'll double check for the place where the SDK is loaded again and will not set data-namespace.

Comment: `components` is the other thing that doesn't seem entirely necessary since buttons should be in the default, but I'm not aware of it causing problems

Comment: So I've added `deferLoading` to the `PayPalScriptProvider` and I've tried to load the script in the `useEffect` hook of `PaypalButton` (for testing, I probably wouldn't leave it like this as that hook can fire multiple times). I used the `dispatch` hook from `usePayPalScriptReducer` with type `resetOptions`. The error from the first screenshot is gone, however the second one is still there. It's almost like they're not linked?

Comment: Try a different onInit function, and make a minimal codesandbox that reproduces

Answer (score 0):

For anyone googling for the same issue:
The issue was a past commit that included third party event propagation blocking due to security issues. Simply allowing the PayPal origin to propagate events on our website fixed the issue.

So, if this happens to you, it's most probably due to the fact that the script, doesn't, in fact, really run, and the `PaypalButtons` functions therefore don't exist and thus they cannot be called. It would appear that the status of the script isn't quite reflected accurately in the `isResolved` property returned from `usePayPalScriptReducer`, as it's value was true in my case, but the PayPal script ran with an `undefined` version, as the error said. So watch out for weird environment restrictions.